# Looking for help on installing a numpy extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I found a numpy extension on github that would be really helpful for a program I'm currently writting, however I don't know how to install it.

Here's the link to the extension: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=py_find_1st&:action=display

I'm using windows 10 which might be the reason why the installer provided doesn't work, I found a file looking like a numpy extension as described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html

But there's no mention on this page of where to put the code of the numpy extension, and I didn't manage to find any explanations online.

Would anyone have an idea on how to install this?

Comment: Do you currently have a C compiler?

Comment: To build any extension modules for Python, you’ll need a `C compiler`. Various `NumPy` modules use `FORTRAN 77` libraries, so you’ll also need a `FORTRAN 77` compiler installed.

Answer (score 1):

To build any extension modules for Python, you’ll need a `C compiler`. Various `NumPy` modules use `FORTRAN 77` libraries, so you’ll also need a `FORTRAN 77` compiler installed.

However, if you just want to install the tar.gz file that they have on the website, follow these steps:

1. Open cmd (Command Prompt)
2. Write `set path=%path%;C:\Python27\`
3. Extract the tar.gz file  (use a program like PeaZip)
4. Change directories within the command line (if you are confused on how to do this look [here](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/ice-gt/339) for reference)
5. Get to your files' directory (something like `cd c:\Users\pdxNat\Downloads\py_find_1st1.0.6`)
6. Run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thanks you, I did as you said, however I get a message error doing so: ImportError: No module named 'future'
I imagine that this is an issue within my python librairies, but I have no idea on how to fix it
It might be linked to the fact that I'm using Python 3, but I thought that numpy was working the same way on both versions

Comment: try `pip install future` also

Comment: I got this at the beggining, I managed to install the future module with conda, but now I get an error message that seems linked to the fact that I don't have a compiler installed on my computer, I'm posting the error message as an answer as it is very long

Answer (score 0):

Error message when trying to install the extension using the cmd:

```
D:\Chrome dl\py_find_1st-1.0.6\py_find_1st-1.0.6>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating py_find_1st.egg-info
writing py_find_1st.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to py_find_1st.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to py_find_1st.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\utils_find_1st
copying utils_find_1st\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\utils_find_1st
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 117, in <module>
    zip_safe = False,
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 42, in build_extensions
    if compiler_is_clang(self.compiler.compiler):
AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler'
```